# No data in Allure report

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, allure

I am testing the application within the GitLab pipeline. There is such a script:

```
stages:
    - test
    - report

run_ui_tests:
    tags:
        - est
    stage: test
    before_script:
        - echo "Prepairing enviroment..."
        - python --version
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
    script:
        - echo "Executing ui tests with Pytest..."
        - cd cio_tests
        - dir
        - pytest -v authorize_test.py
    allow_failure: true
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - cio_tests/allure-results/
        expire_in: 5 mins 30 sec
    
reporting:
    tags:
        - est
    stage: report
    needs: 
        - run_ui_tests
    script:
        - cd cio_tests
        - dir
        - allure generate --clean cio_tests/allure-report/
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
            - cio_tests/allure-report/
        expire_in: 5 days
```

The pipeline ends successfully, and Allure report is saved locally on  disk. However, when the report is called in the browser, there is no data in it:[image]

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. To open the built report locally, you need to raise the server in the directory with the allure-report folder.
For this :

1. Go to the directory with the allure-report folder in cmd or shell
2. Run the command: allure open -p  allure-report

Allure report will be open in Edge browser